# PL/SQL 1064 error at line 5 in delete trigger

Tags: plsql

I am trying to create a trigger to delete articles after it deletes of all of its article contents. I am getting a `1064 error at line 5`.

Here is the PL/SQL I have written:

```
delimiter |

create trigger `cleanup_article` after delete on `article_content`
for each row
begin
    declare x int;
    set x = select count(*) as x from `article_content` where id = old.id;
    if x = 0 then
        delete from `article` where id=old.id;
    end if;
end |

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few problems there, due to invalid syntax for PL/SQL:

1. identifiers are either undelimited or delimited using ", not `
2. `declare` must come before `begin`
3. `set` is not a valid keyword. To get the count, use `INTO`, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO x FROM ...`
4. The DELETE statement refers to `old.id`, this should be `:old.id`
5. What's with the "delimiter" statements? Just end the trigger definition with `;`